# Covnerting Linestring (geojson) to geography/geometry using SQL spatial

Tags: sql, json, sql-server, geometry, geojson

My end goal is to convert linestring to wkb using SQL, I tried to do like the function below but it doesn't work for me. I saw some articles for Polygon but nothing for line string. I have a very huge database that have line string for roads and I'm looking for a better way for conversion or if somebody can help in fixing the code
Error shows " A number is expected at position 135 of the input. The input has ,."

````
declare @Road nvarchar(max) = '{
                "type" : "LineString",
                "coordinates" : [
                    [ -1.1956788082, 22.7406770914 ],
                    [ -1.1993641111, 22.7406737999 ],
                    [ -1.1992222243, 22.7412345977 ]
                    ]
            }';


declare @GeoString nvarchar(max) = 
(select 
   '''' + upper(ShapeType) + '(' + 
       replace(
           replace(
                   RePlace(
                      replace(Shape, '[', '')
                   , ',', ' ')
               , ']]', ''),
        ']', ',')
    + ')' + ''''
from  
   openjson(@Road)
with (ShapeType Varchar(64) '$.type',
      Shape nvarchar(max) '$.coordinates' as json)
)

declare @String nvarchar(max) = ( select 'select geography::STGeomFromText(' + @GeoString + ', 4326) as geodata')

exec (@String)```
````

Comment: The easiest way to debug dynamic SQL is to `PRINT`/`SELECT` it. If you do that, you see the problem immediately; your trailing commas.

Comment: It's generally advised to not use syntax such as `EXEC (@SQL);`. Such statements cannot be parametrised, which promote bad habits that result in security flaws like SQL injection. If you need to run a statement that is within a variable or literal string then use [`sys.sp_executesql`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-executesql-transact-sql). Then you can easily parametrise the statement if you need to.

Answer (score 1):

You are halfway towards a solution with your `openjson` usage.  There is no need to convert the whole statement to a string and execute as you can just build the `linestring` required for each road and use within the `STGeomFromText` function.

With the `openjson` you can actually pull out all your `linestring` values in one big set and apply the transformation to all (or a subset based on your filter requirements) within a single statement.  To demonstrate this I have assumed that your data is in a table that has a `RoadID` or similar field alongside the `json` data you currently have in a variable:

### Query

```
declare @Road table(RoadID int, LineString nvarchar(max));
insert into @Road values
 (1,'{
         "type" : "LineString",
         "coordinates" : [
             [ -1.1956788082, 22.7406770914 ],
             [ -1.1993641111, 22.7406737999 ],
             [ -1.1992222243, 22.7412345977 ]
             ]
     }'
 )
,(2,'{
         "type" : "LineString",
         "coordinates" : [
             [ -2.1955555082, 12.3336770914 ],
             [ -2.1995555111, 12.3336737999 ],
             [ -2.1995555243, 12.3332345977 ]
             ]
     }'
 );

select r.RoadID
        ,geography::STGeomFromText('linestring('
                                   + string_agg(replace(replace(replace(s.[value]
                                                                       ,'['
                                                                       ,''
                                                                       )
                                                               ,']'
                                                               ,''
                                                               )
                                                       ,','
                                                       ,' '
                                                       )
                                               ,','
                                               ) within group (order by s.[key])
                                   + ')'
                                  ,4326
                                  ) as LineString
from @Road as r
    cross apply openjson(r.LineString)
    with (ShapeType Varchar(64) '$.type'
            ,Shape nvarchar(max) '$.coordinates' as json
            ) as l
    cross apply openjson(l.Shape) as s
group by r.RoadID
order by r.RoadID;
```

### Output

| RoadID | LineString |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 0xE61000000104030000009B758C0...00002 |
| 2 | 0xE61000000104030000008DF945B...00002 |

### Addendum

For your info though, the error you are getting in your question is due to the generated `linestring` not being formatted correctly.  Due to the way you are building your list of `point` values you are ending up with a trailing comma and parenthesis that shouldn't be there.

Comment: thank you @iamdave.. but should i add 1),2) to my code? because actually I'm using a bulk file to import a geojson file that includes thousands of lines.

Comment: @FadiAkkad Does that bulk file not have other fields within it that identifies the geodata?  I have manually added the `RoadID` values to show you how you can execute this script across an entire dataset, provided you have some way of identifying and grouping the line data.  If you could add the structure and some sample data of the entire file structure to your question, I can give you more specific assistance.